# What is this piece on the Bell 206?

Tags: helicopter

I asked [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/what-was-this-helicopter-doing/) question which led to another question of mine, What it the long rod just past the top of the nose of the Bell 206B helicopter and what is it's purpose?

[image]

Comment: If you mean the blade looking things that angle forward (top and bottom), they are wire cutters. The idea is that if a low flying heli encounters powerlines, those blades will cut the wires before they catch in the skids or rotor.

Comment: The entire "wire cutting" system is not just the knife, there is an abrasive strip running between the two windshield halves that scores the cable first, then the knife cuts it.

Comment: woah! so cool! I never would have guessed

Comment: @mins Your link is dead. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the angled pieces above the front window, and below the nose; they are referred to as the WSPS (wire strike protection system). Designed to shear a line before it wraps around the landing skids or rotor.

Related post: [Is special equipment required to perform high-voltage line inspections?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27641/is-special-equipment-required-to-perform-high-voltage-line-inspections/27643#27643)